# Elasticsearch nodes are not communicating with each other

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed elasticseaerch in two different machine, both the nodes have same cluster name also i configured another setting in order to have a cluster with two nodes but its not getting connected I don't know why. My elasticsearch version is 7.3 in both nodes and i also have kibana in the same machine with node-1, although both elasticsearch is running fine but not getting connected maybe it is because of security issues because i setup certificate thing in elasticsearch because of sercurity purpose. Please check it out.

THANKS.

**node-1 elasticsearch.yml**

```
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: ElasticsearchStaging
#xpack.security.enabled: true
#xpack.security.audit.enabled: true
#xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: node-1
node.master: true
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch/
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: <internal_ip_node-1>
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
cluster.initial_master_nodes: "node-1"
    discovery.seed_hosts:
   - internal_ip_node-1:9200
   - internal_ip_node-2:9200
cluster.initial_master_nodes:
   - node-1
   - node-2
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
#---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.audit.enabled: true
xpack:
  security:
    authc:
      realms:
        native:
          native1:
            order: 0
#xpack.security.audit.enabled: true
#xpack.monitoring.enabled: true
#---------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

**node-2 elasticsearch.yml**

```
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: ElasticsearchStaging
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: node-2
node.data: true
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.master: false
#node.data: true
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: <internal_ip_node-2>
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: 10.128.0.24
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
    discovery.seed_hosts:
   - internal_ip_node-1:9200
   - internal_ip_node-2:9200
cluster.initial_master_nodes:
   - node-1
   - node-2
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_node: 2
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

Comment: Please add your Elasticsearch logs. Zen2 is generally pretty good with logging its problems.

Answer (score 0):

There has been breaking changes in version 7.0 of Elasticsearch.

Your *zen* configuration will no longer work.

[breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#breaking_70_discovery_changes)

Go to the **discovery and cluster formation settings** section and you will find that the new settings are

- discovery.seed_hosts
- cluster.initial_master_nodes

[Important discovery and cluster formation settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/discovery-settings.html)

Comment: Thanks for replying, i made the changes in both yml file you can check it, i edited in the question, but still `number_of_nodes: 1`

Comment: The old settings are deprecated, but the cluster should still form with them. The problem must be somewhere else (firewall, certificates,...)